# How to move Behaviors out into separate classes

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

I'm new to Design Patterns and I've been struggling to work out how I can apply either the Strategy, Decorator or perhaps Visitor patterns to my issue.

I have a WPF MVVM dialog that is used to capture Letter document information.
The form has the following:

- a group of Recipient Contacts
- a Sender 1 Contact
- a Sender 2 Contact
- a group of CC Contacts
- a group of BCC Contacts

I've used 3 User Controls for the items above because slightly different information is captured for each:

- Recipients
- Sender
- CCs (used by BCCs)

I have a single Contact class and slightly different information is captured by each ViewModel. Where it differs is that Recipients/CCs have a 'Multiple Contacts' behavior and Sender/CCs have a 'Favorite Contact' behavior.

Currently my logic is duplicated and I'm trying to make it more maintainable.

When I looked into the Strategy and Decorator patterns, the super class contained information about every behavior. Is it possible to just 'Add' behavior to a concrete implementation without adding to the super class?

Answer (score 0):

You can "add" behavior to a concrete type w/out inheriting using `extension methods`, depending on what type of functionality you need to add.

For example, say you have a class called `MyConcreteClass` like so:

```
public class MyConcreteClass
{
   public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
   public void MethodOne { ... }
}
```

You can then create a separate extension class, that allows you to add functionality without modifying the original implementation.

```
namespace Extensions
{
    public static class MyConcreteClassExtensions
    {
        public static string MethodTwo(this MyConcreteClass concreteClass)
        {
               // add new implementation here
               return concreteClass.PropertyOne + " using extensions";
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can simply use as follows:

```
var c = new MyConcreteClass();
Console.WriteLine(c.MethodTwo());
```

For more info, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that I can use an extension method because the behaviors are a too complex.

eg. The Favorites behavior introduces 1) a Collection of favorite contacts 2) additional Commands for 'AddFavorite' and 'RemoveFavorite' and 3) modifies a couple of the existing commands like 'ClearContact'